# JQuery Currency Issue (Not firing)

Tags: jquery, visual-studio

Can anyone tell me what the issue is with this JQuery? It isn't firing at all.... the **txtBoxCost** is the name of the textbox I am wanting to currency format.

```
 $('.txtBoxCost').blur(function () {
     $('.txtBoxCost').formatCurrency();
 });
```

Maybe it is something simple I am just looking over or I am coming at formatting this field from the wrong direction.

Example valid field: **$1,234,300.09**

Updated:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxCost" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>

 $('#txtBoxCost').blur(function () {
 $(this).formatCurrency();
 });
```

Libraries:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//jquery-formatcurrency.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.formatCurrency.js" />
```

Comment: is txtBoxCost an id or a class?  You might want to show the html. Your jquery is reading it as a class

Comment: It is an ID, I can't believe I missed that... Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for.

Using ID:

HTML Code -

```
<input name="txtBoxCost" type="text" id="txtBoxCost" />
```

jQuery Code-

```
$('#txtBoxCost').blur(function () {
     $(this).formatCurrency();
 });
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/cqsbkru1/

Using Name:

HTML Code -

```
<input type='text' name='txtBoxCost'/>
```

jQuery Code -

```
$("input[name='txtBoxCost']").blur(function () {
$(this).formatCurrency();
 });
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/L0ouvrxu/

Using Class:

HTML Code -

```
<input type='text' class ='txtBoxCost'/>
```

jQuery Code -

```
$('.txtBoxCost').blur(function () {
     $(this).formatCurrency();
 });
```

Working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/hxqzwj32/

Comment: I added my html line in my question.... I tried the first solution you provided and gave me an exception error

Comment: @programmerGuy  Please check now. You updated the question with HTML so I have updated the answer. Try first solution which is using ID.

Comment: It gives me a javascript runtime error.... I have updated the code I am using in my question

Comment: @programmerGuy Please check the fiddle that I have provided. It is working fine.

Comment: makes no sense to me why it isn't working in my form, but is in the fiddle

Comment: @programmerGuy Check whether you have included required jQuery library files. Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: jQuery library and http://jquery-formatcurrency.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.formatCurrency.js

Comment: In my fiddle I added jQuery 1.9.1 and http://jquery-formatcurrency.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.formatCurrency.js

Comment: I just updated my question with imported libraries... Still no luck

Comment: @programmerGuy Instead of <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jquery-formatcurrency.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.formatCurrency.js" /> it should be
<script type="text/javascript" src="//jquery-formatcurrency.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.formatCurrency.js"></script>

Comment: throwing exception on this line "                     $(this).formatCurrency();"